# Best way to aggregate by key(spark/cql)

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cql

Given a simple table with the columns

> id(partition), timestamp(clustering column) and value(a long)

, whats the best way to get the sum of values for each id? I'd try to select all distinct ids in a query and then use this list of ids to run a query for each id

> SELECT sum(value) FROM mytable WHERE id = ?

Unfortunately I cant figure out how to write the spark job and I am not really sure this is the best way. This is how far I got:

```
sc.cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "mytable")
  .select("select distinct id")
  .select("select sum(value)")
  .where("id=?", ???)
```

Any hints on how I should proceed would be really appreciated.

Edit: Also here is an working example of how I currently do the aggregation: https://gist.github.com/Phil-Ba/72a7e762c8ab1ff1f3c9e8cff92cb223#file-cassandrasum-scala

The performance is lackluster though :/

Answer (score 0):

This is called group by.

it can achieved with sql

```
select sum(value) from mytable group by id
```

it can achieved with function call in Spark

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sqlContext.table("mytable")
df.groupBy("id").agg(sum($"value"))
```

Comment: Since cassandra doesnt have a built-in goup by, wouldnt this be the same as using .keyBy(row => (row.getLong("id"))) and then using an.aggregateByKey ? I tried that and the performance wasnt really great.

Comment: are you using datastax/spark-cassandra-connector? can you try if directly using sql works? https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#accessing-cassandra-with-sparksql-since-11

Comment: I am using the cassandra connector. Ill try spark sql tomorrow.